# how to upload photo in album and create a feed at the same time for the new facebook user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo, facebook-wall

I want to post photos into facebook, and also create a feed for the photo I posted at the same time.

It works when I post photo to the wall, but when I posted to the album, it will create a feed with the photo on the first time. After that, it only create a text message says "bla bla bla post a photo in XXX album".

**Here is the problem**:
when user is new for facebook, his wall is non-exsist.The wall will be created after user post a feed with photo on website.

**Question:**
So, at this time, how can I post photo for such users and create a feed at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a picture you can use the response to ad the picture. share the picture.
Scenario 2 in this example shows how to do so and get the repsons with PHP.
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

With that response you could create a feed dialog:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

And put together the URL for the image using the response from the photo upload.
If you run into trouble showing the image, you might need to use a proxy to load it. Facebook sometimes gives you trouble when adding an image that is comming from their CDN in a feed post.